# Add mouse click event in Powershell

Tags: function, powershell, click, eventhandler

```
function a1
{
    Set-Clipboard -Value "This is a test string"
}
```

How to create a mouse click event in PowerShell. Whenever I click on the form the above function should run.

Comment: There is not much context for us to help you. What form are you referring to?

Comment: `$form.Add_Click({..])`